# Jquery next() not working on span

Tags: jquery

I have html that looks like this:

```
<span class="subHeader">Line of Business: </span>
<br>
<span class="sk-hits-grid-hit__state" style="margin: 5px; text-align: center;">General Liability,Workers Comp,</span>
```

I want to grab "General Liability,Workers Comp," as a string.

With jQuery I can get the correct subHeader by

```
$('.subHeader').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() === "Line of Business";
})
```

(I have other subHeaders so I have to check the text). I want to grab the sibling span element. I have tried both sibling() and next(), neither of which are returning anything. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `.siblings()` and this will get the span you mentioned

```
$('#subHeader').siblings('span.sk-hits-grid-hit__state').text()
```

Ex:

```js
console.log($('#subHeader').siblings('span.sk-hits-grid-hit__state').text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="subHeader">Line of Business: </span>
<br>
<span class="sk-hits-grid-hit__state" style="margin: 5px; text-align: center;">General Liability,Workers Comp,</span>
```

Or `$('#subHeader').next().next().text()` (two nexts due to the `<br>`)

```js
console.log($('#subHeader').next().next().text())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="subHeader">Line of Business: </span>
<br>
<span class="sk-hits-grid-hit__state" style="margin: 5px; text-align: center;">General Liability,Workers Comp,</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can leverage the `.filter()` method by chaining it to the `.siblings()` method.  This code assumes that there is a one-to-one ratio between each `span.subHeader` and `span.sk-hits-grid-hit__state`

> **HTML**

```
<span class="subHeader">Line of Business: </span>
<br>
<span class="sk-hits-grid-hit__state" style="margin: 5px; text-align: center;">General Liability,Workers Comp,</span>
```

> **CSS**

```
.subHeader {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: .83em;
  font-family: arial;
}

.turn_blue {
  color: blue;
  font-size: .83em;
  font-family: arial
}
```

> **JavaScript/jQuery**

```
var sub_headers_array = $('.subHeader').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "Line of Business: ";
});

sub_headers_array.each(function(index, current_cell) {
    var business_text_span = $(current_cell).siblings().filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() === "General Liability,Workers Comp,";
    });

    business_text_span.addClass('turn_blue')

    console.log(business_text_span);
});
```

```js
var sub_headers_array = $('.subHeader').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() === "Line of Business: ";
});

sub_headers_array.each(function(index, current_cell) {
  var business_text_span = $(current_cell).siblings().filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "General Liability,Workers Comp,";
  });

  business_text_span.addClass('turn_blue');

  console.log(business_text_span);
});
```

```css
.subHeader {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: .83em;
  font-family: arial;
}

.turn_blue {
  color: blue;
  font-size: .83em;
  font-family: arial
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="subHeader">Line of Business: </span>
<br>
<span class="sk-hits-grid-hit__state" style="margin: 5px; text-align: center;">General Liability,Workers Comp,</span>
```